# Embedding vimeo with javascript api on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, api, vimeo

I'm trying to use vimeo's javascript api (http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) to control an embedded video through my app, but I can't even get their example to work (http://jsfiddle.net/bdougherty/HfwWY/light/)

I tried downloading both the jquery and frogaloop javascripts the fiddle uses, and copied them  into xcode, I also made sure to place them on Bundle Resources instead of Compile Sources as people suggests.

On my `ViewController` I have:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vimeo" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[_webby loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

Then my `vimeo.html` looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="player1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27855315?api=1&player_id=player1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>

<p>Video status: <span class="status">...</span></p>
<p><button>Play</button> <button>Pause</button></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>

</body>
```

Where `jquery.min.js` is https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js and `froogaloop2.min.js` is http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js

Then my `player.js` is like the fiddle example with ondomready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var iframe = $('#player1')[0],
    player = $f(iframe),
    status = $('.status');

// When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    status.text('ready');

    player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
});

// Call the API when a button is pressed
$('button').bind('click', function() {
    player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});

function onPause(id) {
    status.text('paused');
}

function onFinish(id) {
    status.text('finished');
}

function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
    status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
}
 });
```

Also the documentation stands that: "You’ll need to be running on a web server instead of opening the file directly in your browser. Flash and JS security restrictions will prevent the API from working when run locally."

Not sure how to NOT open js directly with my browser, as someone suggested I tried to change this line on my `ViewController`:

```
[_webby loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

to something like this:

```
[_webby loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://player.vimeo.com/"]];
```

Didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was able to make it work doing this:

1. You have to set your base URL with `http://player.vimeo.com` as you mentioned, otherwise it won't work.
2. I wasn't able to make it work referencing local js files. I had to use the remote source. I mean:

   ```
   <script src="http://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
   ```
3. I haven't used jquery, I get rid from that code. Basically my code looks like:

   ```
       var iframe = document.getElementById('player1');
       var player = $f(iframe);

       player.addEvent('ready', function()
       {
           sendNotification('onReady', '');

           player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
           player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
           player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
       });

       function onPause(id)
       {
           sendNotification('onStateChange', 'paused');
       }

       function onFinish(id)
       {
           sendNotification('onStateChange', 'finished');
       }

       function onPlayProgress(data, id)
       {
           sendNotification('onPlayTime', data.seconds);
       }

       function sendNotification(action, data)
       {
           var message = {};

           message['action'] = action;
           message['data'] = data;

           window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage(message);
       }
   ```